# Extracting and storing a query parameter from any page in a web2py app

Tags: web2py

I want the user to be able to append an affiliate ID key and value as the query string on any URL in my web2py app. Which I then register in the session. At any point should they click a link to register:

1. I use the affiliate ID that is in the query string (if there is one)
2. I use the affiliate ID in the session object (if one is there)
3. I randomly choose a user from the database as the affiliate otherwise

My question is: how can I "decorate" each function in the web2py app such that it extracts and assigns the query variable `affiliate` to the session variable `affiliate` without manually writing such code in each and every function in every controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, model files in the top level of the `/models` folder are executed on every request, so just put the code in a model file:

```
if request.get_vars.affiliate:
    session.affiliate = request.get_vars.affiliate
```

Also, using the above, there would be no need for your step #1 above (i.e., pulling the affiliate ID from the query string) -- if "affiliate" is in the query string, it will also be copied to the session within the same request. So, just read the ID from the session.